# What causes this mysterious pylint E1101 error?

Tags: python, pylint

I have following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                 
"""pylint behavior test"""                                                            
                                                                                      
                                                                                      
def autodetect_method(method, data):                                                  
    """autodetect method"""                                                           
    if not method:                                                                    
        method = 'POST' if data else 'GET'                                            
    else:                                                                             
        method = method.upper()                                                       
                                                                                      
    return method
```

`pylint` produces the following error:

```
tt.py:10:17: E1101: Class 'method' has no 'upper' member (no-member)
```

Error is not reported if I rename `method` variable to something else, f.e. to `method_name`!
So, I know several ways to get rid of this error message. But I am very curious what is so special with variable name `method` and why the error is generated?

Just in case this problem is version-specific, my versions are:

```
$ pylint --version
pylint 2.4.4
astroid 2.3.3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the way you could satisfy your curiosity - debugging.
You could run `pylint` from the same file and trace its behavior.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pylint
    import sys
    sys.argv.append(__file__)
    pylint.run_pylint()
```

Actually it's easier to say than to do, I've tried, but was unable to understand what exactly happens in details. In high-level terms, `pylint` tries to infer the type for `method` in the expression `method.upper()`, unable to do it itself, falling into `astroid` library, and there the `method` type inferred as `ClassDef.method`. Obviously the word `method` means something special for `astroid`, as some other words. For example, the same `E1101` error would detected if you use name `function` instead of `method`.

Looks like it's behavior somehow relate to builtin's names, but `function` and `method` are not builtins. I guess `astroid` treats them as some kind if "aliases" for `ast` classes, but I'm not sure.